# Elasticsearch querying doesn't bring any hit

Tags: python, elasticsearch

i'm trying to search elasticsearch with python the last events from the last 5 minutes. But I'm getting this answer with no hits. This is ES answer:

```
{"hits": {"hits": [], "total": 0, "max_score": null}, "_shards": {"successful": 45, "failed": 0, "total": 45}, "took": 13, "timed_out": false}
```

And I know there are hits because I see them in Kibana.

This is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import certifi
import datetime

def get_events():
    es = Elasticsearch([ELASTIC_SEARCH_ENDPOINT],use_ssl=True)
    from_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_date = datetime.datetime.now()
    query = {"query":
                {
                    "range":
                    {
                        "timestamp":
                        {
                            "gte": from_date,
                            "lte": to_date
                        }
                    }
                }    
            }
    res = es.search(index="logstash-*", body=query)
    print '########### recent events ############'
    print res
    return res
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp which is being stored in Elasticsearch is in the same timezone(UTC or your machine time) as from_date and to_date (which is being used in query).
This can be the reason why you are not seeing any result.

Comment: I don't have access to the machine, because I'm using ElasticSearch Service

Comment: You can give UTC time range

Comment: How? I don't find the option in AWS console

Comment: In query, use utc time for for from_time and to_time instead of local timezone time.